# Linq Extension method for Join

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am in the process of learning LINQ, ASP.NET, EF, and MVC via online video tutorials. I would love some help understanding Joins in LINQ extension method syntax.

For simplification, I have two tables (these map to a SQL DB):

```
User Table:
    public int userID{get;set;}
    public string firstName{get;set;}
    ...

Address
    public int ownerID{get;set;}
    public int value{get;set;}
    public string Nickname{get;set;}
    public string street{get;set;}
    public string zip{get;set;}
    ...
```

Let's say I want to find all the property that a particular user owns. I believe I can do something like this:

```
var test = db.User
    .Join(db.Address, user => user.userID, add => add.ownerID, (user, add) => new { user, add });
Source: http://byatool.com/c/linq-join-method-and-how-to-use-it/
```

This should be equivalent to

```
SELECT * FROM User a JOIN Address b on a.userID = b.ownerID
```

Please confirm that this is correct.

Now, what if I wanted to find all property that a particular user owns that has a `value greater than x`. Let's take it a step further and say x is a result from another LINQ query. How do I force execution of `x` inside of a second query? Do I even have to consider this, or will LINQ know what to do in this case?

Thanks

EDIT:
When I try to use the result of a query as a parameter in another, I am required to use a greedy operator to force execution. Many people like to use `.Count()` or `.ToList()`. I only expect `x` (from example above) to return 1 string by using `.Take(1)`. If I append `ToList()` to the end of my first query, I am required to use x[0] in my second query. This seems like a messy way to do things. Is there a better way to force execution of a query when you know you will only have 1 result?

Comment: Sounds like you can just try it and found out for yourself if it will work, or what will happen.  You seem to have an idea of what to try.  If, after a few attempts, you can't get it to work, posting your code here along with the errors you're getting will help us gauge where you're at.

Comment: @Servy I have made some changes to my question. Please review it if you have the chance. Thanks

Comment: It appears you're looking for one of the following: `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single`, `SingleOrDefault`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're trying to do a conditional on a joined model?

```
var query = db.Users.Where(x => x.Addresses.Where(y => y.Value >= yourValue).Any());
```

That will return all users who have a property value greater than `yourValue`.  If you need to return the addresses with the query, you can just add `Include` to your query.  For example:

```
query.Include(x => x.Addresses);
```

You don't need to manually do that `Join` that you have in your example.